# [Searching a string in c++][Using find function giving incorrect results]

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I have a input text file. Its contents are :

```
Time    Content 
Week 01 - 02 (10th  Sep – 24th Oct) - Self verification(ABCD and EFGH)  
- Bring up to
 DynamicPQRSTUVWXYZ 
- Add LMNO feature  
 Week 03 - 04 (25th  Sep  – 08th Oct)   - Add default and Game after
confirmed.  
- Add praying 
table after confirmed.  
Week 05 - 06 (09th  Oct – 21st Oct) -   
- enable feature    
- add &amp;
 security standard  
- check function
```

I want to search a substring(th Oct) in this string. My required Output is "

As soon as it finds the first match of (th Oct)  ,From next line ,print all the lines and characters till it finds the other match of (th Oct).

So in this case my Expected Output is :

```
- Bring up to
  DynamicPQRSTUVWXYZ    
 - Add LMNO feature 
 Week 03 - 04 (25th  Sep  – 08
```

I write the following code in C++.

```
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <sstream>
    int main() {
        std::ifstream ifs("ssrm_bt_plan.txt");
        std::stringstream destText;

        std::string search("th Oct");
        std::string line;
        int flag;
        while (std::getline(ifs, line))
        {
            int r_val = line.find(search);
            if (r_val != -1)
            {
                while (std::getline(ifs, line))
                {
                    r_val = line.find(search);
                    if (r_val != -1)
                        break;
                    std::cout << line << std::endl;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < r_val; j++)
                {
                    std::cout << line[j];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        ifs.close();
    }
```

But the output I am getting is this :

```
- Bring up to
  DynamicPQRSTUVWXYZ    
 - Add LMNO feature      
 Week 03 - 04 (25th┬á Sep┬á ΓÇô 08
```

So i Think when it finds the partial string in 25th Sept, then there is some mistake,either in my code or in find function search in string with spaces.
Can anyone please suggest.This is basically a debugging I am doing taking a small file for a similar problem i got in my project.

Thanks!!.

Comment: This is an encoding issue, not a `find` issue.

Comment: I did not understand how.Can you please help in that.?

Comment: @NikhilSaxena It means the file you are parsing has some non ASCII encoding, what looks like to be non-English characters.

Comment: I pasted the File also I am parsing.Do you know the fix ?